# Glitch when writing to a text file

Tags: java

I am trying to develop a program for a school project. However I am not very experienced with coding, so naturally I run into frequent problems. The whole premise of my project is quite simple, I am creating a Horse Management System, which is basically just fancy wording for a database. Firstly I add information about the horse, such as it's Name, Breed, DOB and other basic information. After that a horse profile has been created. Now you can add information such as it's training schedule, nutritional information and it's past injuries. Today while trying to add information for it's nutrition, I ran into a problem where it just outputs a bunch of random text.[Here's what is written on the text file when I try to write to it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yc7PU.png). I also have a section where you have to pull the data from the file and thus making it editable, but without this section done I can't do anything.

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
boolean entryError = false; 
if(FoodName.getText().equals(""))
{
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Enter the Horse Food Name.","Error.",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE); 
entryError = true; 

}
if(FoodQuantity.getText().equals("")&& entryError==false)
{
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Enter the Horse Food                  
Quantity.","Error.",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE); 
entryError = true; 

}
if(FoodTime.getText().equals("")&& entryError == false)
{
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Enter the Horse FoodTimes.","Error.",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE); 
entryError = true; 

  }

  if(entryError == false)
   {


try {
    FileWriter tWriter = new FileWriter("HorseNutrition.txt",true);
    PrintWriter tPrinter = new PrintWriter(tWriter);

    tPrinter.println(HorseID + "," + FoodName.getText() + "," + FoodQuantity.getText() + "," + FoodTime.getText());
    tPrinter.close(); 

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Nutritional data has been saved.","Info",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE); 


}
catch(Exception error) {
    System.out.println("Error in saving nutritional data");
}
   }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: This looks like you are trying to print out an object which hasn't overloaded `toString()`.  Check your `println()` statement, and call `.toString()` on each variable in there to see what happens.

Comment: That is probably because `HorseID` is a `JTextField` and you're printing it directly to de file instead of printing its text `HorseID.getText()`. Instead of `tPrinter.println(HorseID + "," ....);` try `tPrinter.println(HorseID.getText() + ","...);`

Comment: Thanks for all the help guys. This has fixed the main error but now that it writes to the file, I have realized that the file overwrites with only the information of one horse every time I write to the file. For example, let's say I make Horse1 and input his information, it will write to the file which is good, however once I write in the information for another horse, the file will only write in the information of the last horse I input. Does anyone know why this could be? Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

That **HorseID** seems to be an object (or to be precise, it looks like JTextField object). Outputting it as it is will launch it's .toString() method and output some information about that specific JTextField object. If you want to output the text which you have in that field use:

```
HorseID.getText()
```